# Define a function using another function

Tags: coq, definition

I want to define a translation function g from another function f.

```
Definition trans (f g : Q -> Q) (t : Q) := 
forall q : Q, f (q + t) == g q.
```

In the above code, I implicitly define a translation g.

However, I'm unsatisfied with this definition.

In the case that  a function f is declared,
I want to define a translation function explicitly
with a fixed distance (for example, 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a functional like below ?

```
Definition trans (t:nat){A: Type}(f: nat-> A) := fun n => f (t+n).

Definition g := trans 3 (fun n => 2 * n).

Compute g 10.
```